# How to change Windows 7 Wallpaper using the registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, desktop-customization

All I'm trying to do is get Windows to switch to a different Wallpaper folder at night (a folder containing night images). To achieve this I'm planning to use Task Scheduler to run .bat files which simply switch the names of the two folders around. That's pretty straight-forward.

The only problem is that Windows won't let me rename the folder containing the current Wallpaper image. This means I have to temporarily change the current wallpaper image to something else while I'm renaming the folders.

And to do this I need some kind of file to modify the registry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General\Wallpaper

I did find [a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414635/how-do-i-change-my-windows-desktop-wallpaper-programatically) someone had written which I think does this, but it's too technical for me to understand. I don't know anything about the C language, what classes and namespaces are, or how to create a file that runs this code in Windows. Also, it seems like a lot of code just to change the value of a single registry key. And would I have to install software?

Perhaps someone could give me some help?

Also, could anyone confirm that the Windows wallpaper folder is not kept in the registry? If it was, I could simply change this, and wouldn't have to rename folders. But I've done a lot of searching and can't find any trace of it in the registry.

Answer (score 5):

goto `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
add new string value named "`Wallpaper`" and set it's value to the full path of the image.

Comment: Thank you but I don't believe this helps me to change the wallpaper using Task Scheduler, which is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

[@zebanovich's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1411551/911683) is correct in that `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper` is generally the key used to update the Desktop wallpaper.

Windows doesn't have a specific folder for wallpapers. You can set *any* file path you want in that registry key. Try this batch command:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Folder\File.jpg" /f
start "" /b RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True
start "" /b RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True
start "" /b RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True
start "" /b RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True
start "" /b RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True
```

Replace `C:\Folder\File.jpg` with the *full* path to the file you want to set the wallpaper to. You can run this directly from the command line to give it a try. If it does what you want, then create one batch file for day and one for night, then add two tasks in the task scheduler to match.

The reason for the repeated `RUNDLL32` command is that it seems to only work inconsistently. Repeating it a few times seemed to work for me.

For me it also sometimes stops working altogether. In that case, I had to run `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe & explorer.exe` to get it working again.

If this answer doesn't work for you, please update your question with more information.

Comment: Thank you for this, but the script didn't change the wallpaper. I've done some investigating, and I believe the registry key I need to change is HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General\WallpaperSource

Could you please provide a script which changes this key?

Comment: @LJ I added some more information that may help you. In general, this seems like a terribly inconsistent thing to do through the command line. The registry key you gave me didn't work at all in my Windows 7, but you can try replacing it in the code above to see if it works for you.

Comment: Worthwelle, Thank you so much for the additional help. This new script works! Sometimes I have to run it twice, but it works. My problem now is that this script makes the new wallpaper permanent, disabling "slideshow". I am trying to change to a new folder but keep slideshow running. I don't suppose you have a script that can change the location of the slideshow folder?